# Topological vs smooth (equivariant) bordism group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, cobordism

In Remark 1.31 of [this work](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.01507.pdf), it is claimed that "Standard arguments in Pontryagin-Thom theory imply that the relevant smooth and topological G bordism groups are
isomorphic." The adjective "relevant" should be thought of as the condition that the tangent micro-bundle of the topological manifolds representing elements in the bordism groups admit a vector bundle lifting.

Questions: Is there a precise reference to this fact? Why is such a statement true? (It's better if the answer is not appealing to smoothing theories...) Does the presence of group action complicate the story at all?

Comment: Unfortunately for your preference I think smoothing theory is the key ingredient in this result.

Comment: You can look at "Differentiable Topology" of M. W. Hirsch, Theorem 1.8 and 1.9 in Chapter 8.